# I want to move div back left

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have my BG image set to center and I want to move my main content's div back 
to the left a little on that BG image.

Changing the width of the div won't do it, that just allows me to scroll more
to the right. What I need is for it to move back left a little, but i still need that image center.

How would I code this?

bada-bing

```
<style>
body
{
background-image:url;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center top;
} 
</style>
```

bada-boom

```
<center>
<div style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1200px; height: 1511px;">
<img src=""position: relative; top: 100px; left: -350px;"/>
</div>
</center>
```

Comment: A `<center>` element, really?

Comment: whats your question? i dont understand

Comment: That element has been deprecated for a **long** time and is no longer supported in HTML5. It is *highly* advised you **do not use it**.

Comment: You can set the left property of the div to some negative value.

Comment: @animuson - every major website uses <center> - take a look at the source code for Google, Facebook, etc

Comment: @Fraser: Google uses it because it uses fewer characters, **not** because it's a valid element. They only care about the bandwidth. They're sacrificing HTML validity for other reasons.

Comment: @animuson - That is just speculation - I would say they use it because every single browser renders it correctly. HTML validity is another thing every major website ignores. Why so hung up on validity - when all the professionals ignore it?

Comment: @animuson - also they use <DIV class="whatever"> all over the place - so that kind of blows your argument out of the water...

Comment: @Fraser: [It's actually not speculation.](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2005-11-17-n52.html) We follow standards to make our pages semantic and easier to read by bots, such as Google. If they understand our page, it's more likely to find relevant information. Just because other people don't follow them **doesn't mean you shouldn't** and that's the worst argument you could ever come up with.

Comment: @animuson - just because other people follow them *doesn't mean you should*

Comment: @animuson - also, "We follow standards to make our pages semantic and easier to read by bots" - nothing at all about "because it uses fewer characters" - that is total rubbish...

Comment: @Fraser: You obviously don't understand the purpose of HTML, so there's no point in arguing with you.

Comment: @animuson - pfff you make spurious claims, attempt to back them up with material that doesn't reference the point at all and then attempt to insult me. Pathetic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question... Are you simply wanting the div on top to be more left without changing anything about the body or any other content? Is the left style not working? (left: -50px;) What about margin-left? Maybe I'm confused.

Comment: its like this. i need, say... to be able to see 1100px of the center of a 1200px wide background. im talking about on a small screen. opening up the width of the div wont help because i can only see more to the right now, through scrolling. get it? i need to see more of the left

Comment: So you need to center the div dynamically based on the screen size? I'd use some javascript to get the window width and move the div left as necessary until you get what you're looking for.

Comment: i dont know you tell me. say we're looking at a block 1024px wide in the middle of my background image. i need to get an animated gif to the left of that block. my screen is only 1024 px wide and so far i havent been able to do that and keep the gif visible. i need to be able to scroll back to where that animated gif is now at(to the left of that block in my BG image). is what you said a soultion to my problem?